# Laravel HasMany not returning any results - Doesn't even query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I've been pulling my hair out for the last couple of hours.
I have an existing website which I'm trying to convert over to Laravel, the first step is building an API for it.

I have a Campaign model, and each Campaign has Posts. So there should be a OneToMany relationship between them.

Here is my code so far:

**Campaigns.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Campaigns extends Model
{
    // Define the table name for this model
    protected $table = 'campaign_accounts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

**CampaignPosts.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CampaignPosts extends Model
{
    // Define the table name for this model
    protected $table = 'campaign_posts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

**CampaignsController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\CampaignPosts;

DB::enableQueryLog();

class CampaignsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return \App\Campaigns::all();
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $campaigns = \App\Campaigns::find($id);
        $campaignposts = $campaigns->campaignPosts;
        dd(
            $campaignposts
        );

        return array(
            'status' => 'OK',
            'data' => array(
                'campaign' =>$campaigns,
                'posts' => $campaignposts
            )
        );
    }

    // Define relationship to CampaignPost
    public function campaignPosts()
    {
        // First key is foreign key, second key is local key
        return $this->hasMany('App\CampaignPosts', 'accountid', 'accountid');
    }
}
```

**CampaignPostsController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Campaigns;

class CampaignPostsController extends Controller
{
    // Define relationship to CampaignPost
    public function campaigns()
    {
        // First key is foreign key, second key is local key
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Campaigns', 'accountid', 'accountid');
    }
}
```

When I navigate to /campaigns/ all the campaigns display fine, however when I navigate to campaigns/{id} I only get the result for the campaign itself, I can't get anything from the underlying Campaign Posts.

I tried to use the DB Query Logger, and it looks like there isn't even a query being performed against the campaign_posts table, nothing is happening...

Any thoughts? This is driving me insane.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to put the relationship code in model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

relation methods should move to self models.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Campaigns extends Model
{
    // Define the table name for this model
    protected $table = 'campaign_accounts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Define relationship to CampaignPost
    public function campaignPosts()
    {
        // First key is foreign key, second key is local key
        return $this->hasMany('App\CampaignPosts', 'accountid', 'accountid');
    }

}
```

and

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CampaignPosts extends Model
{
    // Define the table name for this model
    protected $table = 'campaign_posts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Define relationship to CampaignPost
    public function campaigns()
    {
        // First key is foreign key, second key is local key
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Campaigns', 'accountid', 'accountid');
    }

}
```